# what is the characters behind the characters down the line?

Tags: android

I am converting between "\n" to ":" in file .txt. And here, this is my paragraph before convert:

[image]

You can see that, between string "Hoa"  and string "Đàm", it have one character " " and two character "\n". And this is my convert function:

```
private String convertData(){
    String different = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+*/\\\"'|]}{[:;?/.><,\n ";
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(tvData.getText().toString().trim());
    for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++){
        if(different.contains("" + data.charAt(j))) data.setCharAt(j, ':');
    }
    String convertData = data.toString().trim();
    return convertData;
}
```

And this is result:
[image]

You can see behind character "\n" have a character, and it is not in string different.
Can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** - Proceed like you're currently doing, **but** the `\n` (and the other escaped sequences).

So, use

```
String different = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+*/'|]}{[:;?/.><, ";
```

**2** - After the loop, use `string.replace()` to replace only the substring `"\n"` and the other sequences, i.e.: `"\\"` and `"\""`.
You could use a loop to replace the sequences, but you must replace 2 characters instead of one.

---

Basically, in the first loop you replace all the **single characters**.
Then, you replace the character sequences.

Comment: It works for sure. Just replace FIRST the single characters. THEN the sequences (one at a time or in a loop).

Comment: my convert function: 
private String convertData(){

        String different = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+*/\\\"'|]}{[:;?/.><, ";

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(tvData.getText().toString().trim());

        for (int j = 0; j < data.length(); j++){

            if(different.contains("" + data.charAt(j))) data.setCharAt(j, ':');

        }

        String convertData = data.toString().trim().replace("\n", ":");

        return convertData;

    }


but the result is not change !!! i think behind the character "\n" have one character, but i don't know it.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad only supports Windows line endings (`\r\n`), so that must be what your file contains. Convert the file to Unix line endings (`\n`) using literally any program that is not Notepad, or add `\r` to your search pattern.